# SELECT statement using NOT IN against a text string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a `SELECT` statement that returns value but excludes any that appear in a text list

So I have a text list `COL1, COl2, COL4, COL5` (called `myString`)

And I want to say...

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'INTERFACE' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN(myString);
```

How would I do that?

I am trying to solve this problem in a stored procedure and though that just getting back to basics would help me understand. My SP code looks like this...

```
INSERT INTO @excludeFieldTable VALUES ('CASENO'),('INTLINENO'),('INTMEMBNO'),('INTSTATUS'),('RECTYPE'),('EFFDTE'),('INTERR'),('INTERR2'),
('INTWARN'),('AUTHORISED'),('EXCLUDE'),('UPDATED'),('INTMEMBNO2'),('INTSTATUS2'),('ALTKEY');

    INSERT INTO @intColumnList SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='INTERFACE' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(excludeFieldName) FROM @excludeFieldTable);
```

but the `NOT IN` against the `@excludeFieldTable` is not evaluating for some reason (so `intColumnList` still has the values 'CASENO', 'INTLINENO' etc)

Comment: Check out the following solution http://www.spyriadis.net/2010/12/convert-a-comma-separated-nvarchar-to-a-list-that-can-be-used-in-any-t-sql/

Comment: Sorry for answer with way too many mistakes, @freefaller and Mike. Was going to try to fix, bu t thought better to remove instead. Did too fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a **single** comma seperated string into the `IN` clause. Either use seperate values of put it together dynamically using `EXEC`

```
exec('SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME=''INTERFACE'' 
      AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (' + @myString + ')')
```

Comment: You need double "single quotes" on the `INTERFACE`

Answer (score 1):

```
Exec('
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME=''INTERFACE'' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN(' + @myString + ')')
```

Another popular option is to use a split function and then join to it:
See here: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/

Comment: You need double "single quotes" on the `INTERFACE`

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why your approach is not working. Check again at your code :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE INTERFACE
    ([ID] int, 
     [COL1] varchar(2), 
     [COL2] varchar(2), 
     [COL3] varchar(2), 
     [COL4] varchar(2), 
     [CASENO] int,
     [INTLINENO] int,
     [INTMEMBNO] int,
     [INTSTATUS] int,
     [RECTYPE] varchar(2),
     [EFFDTE] date,
     [INTERR] int,
     [INTERR2] int,
     [INTWARN] int,
     [AUTHORISED] varchar(12),
     [EXCLUDE] varchar(10),
     [UPDATED] varchar(6),
     [INTMEMBNO2] int,
     [INTSTATUS2] int,
     [ALTKEY] varchar(12),
     [COL5] varchar(2))
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @excludeFieldTable TABLE
(
  excludeFieldName varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @excludeFieldTable VALUES 
('CASENO'),('INTLINENO'),('INTMEMBNO'),('INTSTATUS'),
('RECTYPE'),('EFFDTE'),('INTERR'),('INTERR2'),
('INTWARN'),('AUTHORISED'),('EXCLUDE'),('UPDATED'),
('INTMEMBNO2'),('INTSTATUS2'),('ALTKEY')


DECLARE @intColumnList TABLE
(
  columnList varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @intColumnList 
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='INTERFACE' AND 
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(excludeFieldName) FROM @excludeFieldTable)

SELECT *
FROM @intColumnList
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/2/0)**:

```
| COLUMNLIST |
|------------|
|       COL1 |
|       COL2 |
|       COL3 |
|       COL4 |
|       COL5 |
|         ID |
```

EDITED :

With a string, it can look like this :

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE @excludeFieldTable VARCHAR(1000)

SET @excludeFieldTable = 'CASENO, INTLINENO, INTMEMBNO, INTSTATUS, RECTYPE, EFFDTE, INTERR, INTERR2, INTWARN, AUTHORISED, EXCLUDE, UPDATED, INTMEMBNO2, INTSTATUS2, ALTKEY'

DECLARE @intColumnList TABLE
(
  columnList varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @intColumnList 
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='INTERFACE' AND 
', '+@excludeFieldTable+', ' NOT LIKE '%, '+COLUMN_NAME+', %'

SELECT *
FROM @intColumnList
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/11/0)**:

```
| COLUMNLIST |
|------------|
|       COL1 |
|       COL2 |
|       COL3 |
|       COL4 |
|       COL5 |
|         ID |
```

**RE-EDITED :**

SP working fine also :

**Query 3**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExcludeField1 AS
DECLARE @excludeFieldTable VARCHAR(1000)

SET @excludeFieldTable = 'CASENO, INTLINENO, INTMEMBNO, INTSTATUS, RECTYPE, EFFDTE, INTERR, INTERR2, INTWARN, AUTHORISED, EXCLUDE, UPDATED, INTMEMBNO2, INTSTATUS2, ALTKEY'

DECLARE @intColumnList TABLE
(
  columnList varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @intColumnList 
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='INTERFACE' AND 
', '+@excludeFieldTable+', ' NOT LIKE '%, '+COLUMN_NAME+', %'

SELECT * FROM @intColumnList
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/28/0)**:

**Query 4**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExcludeField2 AS
DECLARE @excludeFieldTable TABLE
(
  excludeFieldName varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @excludeFieldTable VALUES 
('CASENO'),('INTLINENO'),('INTMEMBNO'),('INTSTATUS'),
('RECTYPE'),('EFFDTE'),('INTERR'),('INTERR2'),
('INTWARN'),('AUTHORISED'),('EXCLUDE'),('UPDATED'),
('INTMEMBNO2'),('INTSTATUS2'),('ALTKEY')

DECLARE @intColumnList TABLE
(
  columnList varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @intColumnList 
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='INTERFACE' AND 
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(excludeFieldName) FROM @excludeFieldTable)

SELECT * FROM @intColumnList
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/28/1)**:

**Query 5**:

```
EXEC ExcludeField1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/28/2)**:

```
| COLUMNLIST |
|------------|
|       COL1 |
|       COL2 |
|       COL3 |
|       COL4 |
|       COL5 |
|         ID |
```

**Query 6**:

```
EXEC ExcludeField2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/28/3)**:

```
| COLUMNLIST |
|------------|
|       COL1 |
|       COL2 |
|       COL3 |
|       COL4 |
|       COL5 |
|         ID |
```

If you want to define the exclude string before, it will look like this :

**Query 7**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExcludeField1 @excludeFieldString varchar(1000) AS

DECLARE @intColumnList TABLE
(
  columnList varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @intColumnList 
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='INTERFACE' AND 
', '+@excludeFieldString+', ' NOT LIKE '%, '+COLUMN_NAME+', %'

SELECT * FROM @intColumnList
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/30/0)**:

**Query 8**:

```
DECLARE @excludeFieldTable VARCHAR(1000)

SET @excludeFieldTable = 'CASENO, INTLINENO, INTMEMBNO, INTSTATUS, RECTYPE, EFFDTE, INTERR, INTERR2, INTWARN, AUTHORISED, EXCLUDE, UPDATED, INTMEMBNO2, INTSTATUS2, ALTKEY'

EXEC ExcludeField1 @excludeFieldString = @excludeFieldTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd117/30/1)**:

```
| COLUMNLIST |
|------------|
|       COL1 |
|       COL2 |
|       COL3 |
|       COL4 |
|       COL5 |
|         ID |
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabien - could it be the data types - I see your 2 tables both have varchar(5) - my excludeFieldTable has varchar(100) - would it still work if this was a different setting to the COLUMN_NAME column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table?

Comment: I ran your code on the query pane and it worked. I ran it again from my SP and it did not. Is there anything I need to do to "commit" the insert to the excludeFieldTable before I then reference it in the NOT IN query?

Comment: I edited my answer to consider your actual fields. There is nothing special to do.

Comment: SP code is added in the answer...working well also...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to all (and a huge thanks for your time) - there was a small typo in my SP code

Comment: I was almost sure that it was the code :)

Comment: @FabienTheSolution - you were absolutely correct. Thanks again for taking the time to help me. Really appreciate it